# GetNodeByXpath throws NullReferenceException

Tags: xpath, umbraco

This line below throws a NullReferenceException.

```
Node nodeEmail = Node.GetNodeByXpath("//Member/email[text()='xxx']");
```

and I've got

```
<root id="-1">
  <Members>
    <Member id="15853" ...>
      <email>xxx</email>
    </Member>
    ...
```

Exception:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   umbraco.NodeFactory.Node.initialize() +172
   umbraco.NodeFactory.Node..ctor(XmlNode NodeXmlNode) +179
   umbraco.NodeFactory.Node.GetNodeByXpath(String xpath) +168
```

This is the first time I try XPath. It is on Umbraco 6.
What did I do wrong?

**More info**
Below are fine:

```
Node nodeEmail = Node.GetNodeByXpath("//Members");
Node nodeEmail = Node.GetNodeByXpath("//Members/Member");
Node nodeEmail = Node.GetNodeByXpath("//Member");
```

but this throws the same exception

```
Node nodeEmail = Node.GetNodeByXpath("//Members/Member/email");
```

Comment: From both xpath and XML you posted so far, nothing wrong. That should work, you can test the xpath [here](http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html) (or any other xpath tester).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works

```
Node nodeMember = Node.GetNodeByXpath("//Member[email='"+email+"']");
```

Of course it threw an exception because what I tried to select wasn't a Node. Sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 0):

Change `text()` to `.` like this:

```
Node nodeEmail = Node.GetNodeByXpath("//Member/email[.='xxx']");
```